# Looking for simple explanation of `CloudKit` code - inZoneWith and Void in

Tags: swift, cloudkit, void

I have my successful code which run a query search from my cloud kit database but I haven't come across a solid explanation of the `inZoneWith: nil` portion and the `(results, error) -> Void in` piece, specifically the `->Void in` portion. Would you be able to help me understand the purpose of these two sections?

```
 publicDB.perform(query, inZoneWith: nil)
    {
        (results, error) -> Void in
```

Comment: Have you read the documentation for the `CKDatabase perform(_:inZoneWith:completionHandler:)` method?

Comment: I have not. I'll take a look at it though. Thank you!